# Codeigniter, routing is not functioning on production server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have 3 servers, a localhost apache server, a testing remote server and the production live server.

I have the same installation of codeigniter and site set-up on all 3 of them and on the localhost and testing servers routing without 'index.php' works 100%. On the Production server however, no matter what the URL says only the homepage (via the default controller) will be shown, it seems all routing rules are being ignored except the default one.

If however index.php is added in the URL then it will work like it supposed to.

For instance if the URL on the production site is: 'www.mysite.com/information' then the content that loads is form the default controller.

But when the URL on the production site is: 'www.mysite.com/index.php/information' then the content that loads is from the 'information' controller.

This is the contents of my htacess file: http://pastebin.com/cDaZVJ8A

This is my routes config file: http://pastebin.com/7Ewc2bwN

My $config['index_page'] is set to nothing.

I really dont know why its not working, the same setup on all servers in term of codeigniter itself, and mod_rewrite IS working on the production server.

I don't know what to do, how can I find-out what's wrong?

Comment: Did you check whether `routes.php` exists in `application/config/production` directory? If the file exists it will overrides the one in `application/config` directory.

Comment: @Stanley, it does exist on the production server in the correct place.

Comment: @Stanley, wait what? there are no folders within the config directory?

Comment: Different configuration file could be loaded depending on the ENVIRONMENT constants defined in `index.php`. I am just suspecting that the actual routes config loaded in production is not the one you are looking at. [About Environments](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html#environments)

Comment: @Stanley, wow that is a really awesome feature. But there are no subdirectories in my config folder and I have not setup different config for different environments.

Comment: If another one is loading, I don't know where it is or why.

Comment: @Ezra make sure that on your live server the rewrite module has been installed.

Comment: @SubRed, the mod_rewrite module !IS! installed and works correctly.

Comment: @Ezra, are your Test and Live servers run by different hosts? If your running on DreamHost may be worth doing a search for `codeigniter dreamhost` on SO, as I know Codeigniter has some issues with Dreamhosts setup.

Comment: @Jeemusu, they are on different hosts. Not dreamhost however. hostgator.com for the test server and openhost.co.nz for the production server.

Comment: @Ezra What does your `.htaccess` look like? Try adding a question mark to the index.php rewrite rule - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274321/codeigniter-unable-to-remove-index-php-from-url . I know some hosts have problems with the standard code provided by the Codeigniter userguide.

Comment: @Jeemusu look in my question, you will see i've posted a link to the contents of my htacces file.

Comment: @Ezra Try changing the index.php line to this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: @Jeemusu, im not using the code from the userguide as it is out of date. The issue seems to be more with routing that the htaccess file.

Comment: Really, why do you think it has anything to do with routing? If the same code works on your local & test servers then it's fairly obvious that the problem is the difference in environment, and one common problem is the one I posted in the comment above. Just give it a try, you'd be surprised how often this question pops up, and how often that `?` questionmark is the answer.

Comment: @Jeemusu, woops forgot to try it. Sorry I doubted you, it works!. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Ezra Sadly, I'm not entirely sure why it happens, other than it being a difference in server environments. It crops up a lot though.

Comment: Please do not reference code source to another sites. You files have been taken down and now viewers cannot get benefit from this question as they should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is quite a common problem that often occurs when people move a codeigniter install from one environment to another. I have no idea why it occurs, could be a difference in server OS or apache settings, but the solution is often to add a question mark `?` to the RewriteRule for the index.php in your .htaccess file.

Old:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

New:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've never had this problem, but is good to know a possible solution

Answer (score 2):

Check your Apache virtual host configuration and verify that you have `AllowOverride All` in your directory definition.

Comment: I do not have access to that, its a shared server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe something is wrong with your .htaccess file?

   Once I had problem when I moved application to production server, because RewriteBase was set to some directory on development server.

   On my production server application was in web root directory, so `RewriteBase` should be `/`, and i had `/something` there.
2. Once i had silly problem with upper/lowercases, when i moved site from development server (windows) to production (linux).

Comment: I wish it were that easy, you can see my htacess file for urself from the link in the question. It is correct.

Comment: Take a look now @Ezra. I added one more tip.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using function to convert article names to URL's (slugify).

On localhost and on server this function returned slightly different urls.