# Remove index.php from url not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url

This is my .htaccess file:

```
     RewriteEngine On

     RewriteBase /mydomainname.com/
     RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt) 
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This code is working on one hosting while not on the other.
I tried by running this code on the both the hosting

1)on one hosting I have my code works without adding index.php in the url
i.e

```
 www.mydomainname.com/contrlerName/functionname
```

2)On the other domain I need to add index.php in the url
like :

```
 www.mydomainname.com/index.php/contrlerName/functionname
```

what can be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code is the same on both hosting?

Comment: as someone answered before, you must remove RewriteBase /mydomainname.com/ or rename the "mydomainname.com" to your new domain name. And you have to be sure that mod_rewrite is enable, if not contact yor hosting service

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718549/codeigniter-routing-is-not-functioning-on-production-server/13719606#13719606). It is most likely the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Remove teh RewriteBase line, That was probably required on your old one, but not no new. Thats non standard, it shouldn't really of been required. Probably they had some crazy virtual hosting setup.

It might also be your new hosting, doesnt allow .htaccess files, so it simply being ignored.

Comment: Yes, but what is the actual error. Find out the actual error, rather than guessing. Surely you dont do all development by trial and error?

Answer (score 1):

`AllowOverride All|None|directive-type [directive-type]`

Ensure allow override directive enables `.htaccess` file in the second hosting where its not working.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 0):

Just check what mod_rewrite work on your second hosting. Ask hosting support.
There is like that hosting don't support rewrite.

Comment: yes it is not enabled but I am using shared hosting ,any idea how to enable it on shared hosting